# pandas multiple awnsers in one column, How to split?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like...

[image]

or

```
    ConvertedComp LanguageWorkedWith
0   NaN           C#;HTML/CSS;JavaScript
1   NaN           JavaScript;Swift
2   NaN           Objective-C;Python;Swift
3   NaN           NaN
4   NaN           HTML/CSS;Ruby;SQL
```

How could I separate these languages so that each language would be in their own column? and grouped correctly with nan values in between.

so that the expected output would look like.

```
    ConvertedComp   C#   HTML/CSS   python   swift   Ruby   SQL   JavaScript   Objective-C
0   NaN             C#   HTML/CSS   NaN      NaN     NaN    Nan   JavaScript   NaN
1   NaN             NaN  NaN        NaN      Swift   NaN    NaN   JavaScript   NaN
2   NaN             NaN  NaN        Python   Swift   NaN    NaN   NaN          Objective-C
3   NaN             NaN  NaN        NaN      NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN          NaN
4   NaN             NaN  HTML/CSS   NaN      NaN     Ruby   SQL   NaN          NaN
```

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Ive added a code block and added expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) for indicator with cast to boolean and in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) replace values by columns names and `NaN`, pass to `DataFrame` and add to original:

```
mask = df.pop('LanguageWorkedWith').str.get_dummies(';').astype(bool)
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(np.where(mask, mask.columns, np.nan), 
                          columns=mask.columns, 
                          index=df.index))
print (df)
   ConvertedComp   C#  HTML/CSS  JavaScript  Objective-C  Python  Ruby  SQL  \
0            NaN   C#  HTML/CSS  JavaScript          NaN     NaN   NaN  NaN   
1            NaN  NaN       NaN  JavaScript          NaN     NaN   NaN  NaN   
2            NaN  NaN       NaN         NaN  Objective-C  Python   NaN  NaN   
3            NaN  NaN       NaN         NaN          NaN     NaN   NaN  NaN   
4            NaN  NaN  HTML/CSS         NaN          NaN     NaN  Ruby  SQL   

   Swift  
0    NaN  
1  Swift  
2  Swift  
3    NaN  
4    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are reading you data using `pd.read_csv`, then specify `sep=";"`

Comment: i dont think that method would work as this would mix the columns?